# Agregar una celda que diga cuando fue la última actualización

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script en Google Spreadsheets que trae una información de la base de datos cada cierto tiempo mediante unos Triggers.

¿Como puedo colocar una celda dentro del Spreadsheet que me diga cuando fue la ultima actualización?

Alguna luz. Gracias

```
function lastChanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja1');

  var lastUpdated = getLastUpdatedTime('-KEY SPREADSHEET-');
  var lastUpdated = new Date();
  Logger.log(lastUpdated);
  s.getRange('D1').setValue(lastUpdated);
};

  function getLastUpdatedTime(SpreadsheetId) {
  return DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetId).getLastUpdated();
};
```

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo con las update. Ya subo el código abajo.

Comment: No está claro si el código es parte de la pregunta o si lo has publicado haciendo las veces de respuesta. En cualquier caso estas sobreescribiendo el valor de lastUpdated. Por otro lado me surge la duda de si quires la fecha de última actualización de la hoja de cálculo que tiene el script o de un archivo en Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así quedo mi código

Necesitaba una función que se imprimiera la fecha cada vez que se activaran unos "triggers" porque estos traían información de un API para que los que vieran la hoja supieran la ultima actualización que se hizo.

```js
function timestamp(){
  var destino = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IdDelArchivo");
  var sheet = destino.getSheetByName("NombreDeLaHoja");
  var range = sheet.getRange("d1"); //Importante! Debe ir en minúscula
  range.setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`new Date()` te devuelve un objeto de fecha de JavaScript con la fecha y hora en la que fue llamado. Al pasar este objeto a la hoja de cálculo el valor de la celda corresponde a la fecha y hora en la zona horaria de la hoja de cálculo. Es posible que debas ajustar el formato de número de la celda para que se muestre en el formato que de fecha y hora que se ajuste a tus necesidades o preferencias.

Ejemplo:
Este script escribe la fecha y hora actuales en `'Hoja 1'!A1`.

```
function timestamp(){
  var destino = 'Hoja 1!A1';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(destino);
  range.setValue(new Date());

}
```