# Celda que se actualiza con la edicion en Goggle Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hace poco empece a trabajar con los *scripts* de Google Sheets y he estado buscando el como tener una celda la cual se auto actualiza para tener la fecha de la ultima edicion en ella. No he visto mucho por aqui en español solo unos codigos los cuales dejo aqui abajo y todos dan un `#ERROR!` cuando se ejecuta el setValue():

```
function onEdit() { 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get spreadsheet name 
var r = s.getActiveCell(); // store active cell name in current spreadsheet 
var cell1 = 9 // This is the row I want to put values
  if(r.getRow() != cell1) { // Ignores this row (where I put the dates)
    var column = r.getColumn();  // Get column # from active cell
    var time = new Date(); // Get date and time of last mod
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss"); // Format date and time
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell1,column).setValue(time); // put in time in cell
  };
 };
```

(Dejo los comentarios originales del codigo por si ayudan)
Habia pensado en añadir el que esta casilla siempre se moviese cuando se añadiesen mas filas calculando la ultima fila escrita y siendo ese valor mas 2 por ejemplo, en la primera columna, donde se ejecutase este codigo para tener el valor de la ultima edicion pero como he comentado anteriormente no se mucho de JavaScript en general y menos de Google Sheets asi que estoy algo perdido.

¿Alguien tiene idea de como se podria hacer y en especial el cual es el error que esta pasando?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Agregar una celda que diga cuando fue la última actualización](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35257/agregar-una-celda-que-diga-cuando-fue-la-%c3%baltima-actualizaci%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este `script` inserta un `Time Stamp` en la columna que selecciones. Por ejemplo, insertas un nombre en la celda `B2`, entonces en la celda `C2` se inserta automáticamente la fecha y la hora en que se insertó o se editó el nombre. Las columnas y la hoja deben estar nombradas tal como las pongas en el `script`.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-5";                            // Zona horaria Bogotá, Lima, Quito.
  var timestamp_format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";         // Formato Timestamp. 
  var updateColName = "nombre";                      // Cambiar por el nombre de la columna que debe detectar el cambio.
  var timeStampColName = "fecha";                    // Cambiar por el nombre de la columna en la que se debe ver reflejada la fecha y hora.
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('prueba'); // Nombre de la hoja en la que se debe ejecutar este script.

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Las primeras 5 variables son las que debes modificar según tu zona horaria y según los datos que te dejo comentados.

Te adjunto una imagen de como debería ser la estructura de la hoja para este ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Para añadir a la pregunta, habria alguna forma de poner contador en general? En el sentido de un contador con la hora de la ultima modificacion realizada en todo el archivo en vez de modificaciones de cada elemento?

Comment: Esa función ya está incluída en Google Sheets, si te fijas en la imagen que te envié hay un enlace que dice **Última modificación** al final de la barra de menú. Si clicas en ese enlace te muestra un historial de cambios.

Comment: Cierto debí de especificar ya que se me pasó mi caso en especifico. Plane trabajar con una hoja en específico en el sentido de tener varias dentro del mismo documento para varias personas. No me quise referir a todo el documento pero a una hoja en específico.

Comment: No hace falta usar `Utilities.formatDate`, incluso se puede pasar  new Date() como argumento de setValue. `cell.setValue(new Date());` Acá una respuesta con un ejemplo completo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35316/65